# How to put /opt and /home on the same partition but different from /?

Tags: partitioning

I'd like to install Ubuntu on two drives, one with `/` and the other with `/opt` and `/home`. But I do not want `/opt` and `/home` to reside on separate partitions but on the same one. Is it possible to do during the installation?

Answer (score 14):

This is what I would do. Make a home partition, tell the installer to mount it to `/home`. After install and on first boot create a directory called `/home/opt`. Then mount bind it to `/opt`.

Make sure `/opt` is empty before you do this. I would think so if it's just after a fresh install.

```
mount -o bind /home/opt /opt
```

for a manual mount.

For mounting on boot, edit `/etc/fstab` it would look something like this. Make sure you add below your home mount, which the installer should have added.

```
/home/opt /opt none bind 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy with **bind mounts**.  That way, you can mount a subdirectory from one location on another location.

Just make "opt" a subdirectory in your "home" partition, then mount the partition to /home and bind mount /home/opt to /opt:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /home
sudo mount --bind /home/opt /opt
```

Or it can be made permanent by adding them to `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
/dev/sda4   /home   ext4   defaults   0 2
/home/opt   /opt    none   bind       0 0
```

And if you prefer using UUIDs, replace `/dev/sda4` with `UUID=<your UUID>`

Comment: What makes your answer different from the one of @strings? And I fail to see how this relates to the installation.

Comment: Not much, from the looks of it.  I'm afraid I wrote that before looking at the other answers very thoroughly.  At any rate, maybe explaining the same thing 2 different ways isn't such a bad thing on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

#### The LVM way

If you don't mind it being two different volumes, on one partition.

Create an *Physical Volume* on the drive you want to put the `/home` and `/opt` on. Create a *Volume Group* with just this partition as the single member of it. Give it a name, e.g. `myvg`. Then create two *Logical Volumes*, e.g. `homes` and `opt`, both will have a filesystem and the obvious mount points.

Advantages:

- You can do snapshotting.
- Resizing Logical Volumes is a piece of cake compared to resizing partitions.
- Create more volumes without even touching the partition table on a running system.

In order to profit from this, you'll have to keep some free space in the Volume Group.

#### How?

The installer will allow you to do this quite easily in the GUI. For 12.04 you'll need the `alternative` image, for 12.10 and onwards, this is included in the regular images.